# Filter nested object structure

Tags: javascript

I have an object with keys representing a schema. A schema contains a definition of columns and I want to end up with a list of columns that match a specific condition. I can use a for each but think it should also be possible to achieve with a filter or reduce; however getting stuck accessing the nested portion and accumulate the results.

I tried a number of variants, with reduce, spread operators but not achieving the desired result.

Hope anyone can pull me out of the quicksand, I tend to sink deeper with every move I make.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let data = {
    "Schema A" : [{"Id" : "1", "Type" : "measure"}, {"Id" : "2", "Type" : "dimension"}, {"Id" : "3", "Type" : "measure"}],
    "Schema B" : [{"Id" : "4", "Type" : "measure"}, {"Id" : "5", "Type" : "dimension"}, {"Id" : "6", "Type" : "measure"}],
    };

var d = Object.entries(data); // convert to array
console.log(d);

let result = d.map(val => {
    return val.filter(x => x[1].Type === 'measure');
});
console.log(result);
</script>
```

Comment: can you give an input and an expected outut

Comment: The input is in the code sample. The output would be an array of columns, where the condition is matched.

Comment: Please include the expected output in the question - it's not clear at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the values from the key/value entries for filtering.

```js
const
    data = { "Schema A": [{ Id: "1", Type: "measure" }, { Id: "2", Type: "dimension" }, { Id: "3", Type: "measure" }], "Schema B" : [{ Id: "4", Type: "measure" }, { Id: "5", Type: "dimension" }, { Id: "6", Type: "measure" }] },
    result = Object
        .entries(data)
        .map(([k, v]) => [k, v.filter(({ Type }) => Type === 'measure')]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina. Can you perhaps elaborate a bit more about this syntax? filter(({ Type }) => Type === 'measure')])

You are passing a {Type}? I am aware of the .filter(x => x.property === 1234) but this one is new.

Comment: this technique is [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), where a properety is taken from an object and stored in a same named variable.